# Local Cohomology and Maximal-Cohen-Macaulay modules

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, qa.quantum-algebra, homological-algebra, local-cohomology

Checking a recent article [[this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1552), specifically section 3.1] I found the following claim (I'm paraphrasing, of course):

> Let $A$ be a graded connected
>   noetherian algebra (not necessarily
>   commutative), and suppose it is
>   AS-Cohen-Macaulay of depth $d$. If $M$
>   is a finitely generated graded module
>   over $A$, and it is Maximal Cohen
>   Macaulay (MCM, ie, its only non-zero
>   local cohomology module is precisely
>   the $d$-th), then its first syzygy is
>   also MCM.

I have a proof for this in the commutative ungraded case, but it deppends on the fact that $\lbrace i|H^i_{\mathfrak m}(M) \neq 0 \rbrace$ is non-empty and contained in the interval $[0,d]$ (consider the short exact sequence involving $M$ and its first syzygy and look at the long exact sequence of local cohomology). I found  results regarding the non-vanishing of this groups in the non-commutative case, but they demand much more strict conditions than in the paper (finite GK-dimension, enough normal elements, etc.). Any idea on how to prove this in this more general context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know if I'm supposed to, but since I found a solution, I'll write the general idea here.

[This is from an unpublished manuscript by P. Smith, the first author of the paper]: If $A$ is CM, let $\omega_A = H^d_\mathfrak m(A)^*$ be its dualizing module. Then there is a spectral sequence 
$$ E^{pq}_2 = \underline{Ext}^p_A(\underline{Ext}^q(M, \omega_A),\omega_A) \Rightarrow \begin{cases}M&\mbox{ if p = q} \\\  0 &\mbox{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Since $H_\mathfrak{m}^i(M)^* \cong \underline{Ext}_A^i(M,\omega_A)$, the convergence of this SS to a non-zero result guarantees that there must be a non-zero local cohomology module (and in fact, that there is a non-zero one with $i \leq d$)